# Firefox Mobile doesn't highlight visited links

Tags: firefox-for-android, hyperlinks

Firefox for desktop changes visited links to purple but Firefox Mobile fails to mark visited links. The highlighting makes doing research easier.

Is this behaviour by design or is my install broken?

Finally, is there a way to enable marking of visited links in Firefox Mobile?